# The requested URL /wordpress/register/ was not found on this server

Tags: user-registration, installation

So I just installed a brand new version of Wordpress from wordpress.org/download/, extracted it and planted it on my server. Everything was working fine, I enabled "Anyone can register", went to the login page, clicked on Register and was met with a 404 Not Found screen. I haven't deleted any files, I've fully reinstalled WP twice but it still doesn't work. The login.php Register Link links to http://46.101.115.220/wordpress/register/ which doesn't exist. Please let me know how I can solve this.

Comment: Did you change the URL for this?  My default register link is wp-login.php?action=register but if I add that onto your site URL it redirects me.  Perhaps a plugin?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I didn't install any plugins yet, it just set the link to that... (Also I'm the asker, I accidentally posted it anonymously and email verification broke)

Comment: how did you set the link to that?

Comment: I have no idea, come to think it might be a problem with the permalink settings/htaccess file, what do you have selected at wp-admin/options-permalink.php ?

Comment: Common settings = Post Name

Comment: It could be your theme.  You could try temporarily switching themes.